# Why isn't the data in the table displayed when using web sockets to transfer it from the server to the client?

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I have a web application written with Flask. In it, I need to send some data calculated by an algorithm from the server to the client every 10 seconds, for example. I used to do it with Ajax and everything worked, but I decided to switch to web sockets. The problem is that web sockets work fine (at least I don't get any errors in the console), but the data that should be displayed on the html page is not displayed for some reason. I am using Flask SoketIO library.

Server code:

```
@socketio.on('connect').
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

@socketio.on('update_data')
def handle_send_data():
    data = func1()
    emit('update_data', data, broadcast=True)
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + '5000');

socket.on('update_data', function(response) {
    console.log('Received data:', response);
    var tableRows = "";
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
        tableRows += "<tr><td>" + item.symbol + "</td><td><img src='" + item.logo + "' alt='Logo'></img>" + item.b + "</td><td>" + item.c + "</td><td><img src='" + item.d + "' alt='Logo'></img>" + item.e + "</td><td>" + item.f + "</td><td>" + item.g + "</td></tr>."
    });
    $("#data tbody").html(tableRows);
    $("#loading-message").css("display", "none";)
});
});
```

I noticed the following errors in the browser console:

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.**

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received**

I noticed this in the program console:

**Sending packet data None**

**Reeived packet data**

So you can see that the request does not send anything.

I will be glad to receive any advice on how to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: That suggests `func1` isn't returning anything. It would help to see it.

Comment: Make sure the data variable returned from your algorithm is correct and is JSON

Comment: @Carcigenicate No, the algorithm returns data exactly and when I put the code from handle_send_data() function into handle_conect() function everything works, but in this case there are no data updates, they just appear once and that's it.

Comment: @darthbaba when I put the code from handle_send_data() function into handle_conect() function everything works, but in this case there are no data updates, they just appear once and that's it.